# Why do my MongooseJS ObjectIds fail the equality test?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I save and retrieve identical objects as follows

```
var obj1, obj2;

instance.save(function(err, saved) {
    obj1 = saved;
});

Model.find(obj1._id).run(function(err, retrieved) {
    obj2 = retrieved;
});
```

When I print to the console, ObjectIds are the same.  If I call toString on both ObjectIds they are equal.  However doing a straight

```
obj1._id == obj2._id
```

Returns false.  What is happening here?

Answer (score 19):

ObjectIds are objects so a standard == equality test is comparing the references for equality, not the contained id values.  The right way to compare their values is to use ObjectId.equals as:

```
obj1.equals(obj2)
```