# object.valueOf() if returns false

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am baffled as to how if classes in JavaScript work, I've always known it's slightly more complicated but now I just have no idea. Code and output below.

The following json's are stored in mongodb. I'm suspecting this might be where the error is..

console.log(JSON.stringify(user)):

```
{"_id":"5687f787f8ad41175fab5bd5","pic":"karl.png","language":"5687f787f8ad41175fab5bd2","cell":1,"local":{"email":"karl.morrison@email.com","password":"12345"},"profile":{"name":"Karl Morrison"},"sessions":[{"id":"5687f79bf8ad41175fab5bd9","seen":false,"active":false}]}
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(message)):

```
{"authorId":"5687f787f8ad41175fab5bd5","upvotes":0,"created":"2016-01-02T16:15:23.621Z","message":"<p>aa</p>"}
```

Ze code:

```
console.log('"' + user._id.valueOf() + '" "' + message.authorId.valueOf() + '"');

console.log({}.toString.call(user._id).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase());
console.log({}.toString.call(message.authorId).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase());

if (user._id.valueOf() == message.authorId.valueOf()) {
    console.log('TRUE');
} else {
    console.log('FALSE');
}
```

Console:

```
"5687f787f8ad41175fab5bd5" "5687f787f8ad41175fab5bd5"
object
object
FALSE
```

I don't understand why TRUE isn't returned?

Comment: What is the version of mongodb you're using?

Comment: Just using the JSON.stringify output syntax as object literals, [you get `true`](https://jsfiddle.net/9rzbjows/). So it seems mongodb returns an object for the ID, which would mean the `.valueOf()` would most likely return the objects, which would be compared by identity, and therefore `false`.

Comment: try doing a console.print() on the element individually without adding the double quotes, and see what values are returned

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627401/why-do-my-mongoosejs-objectids-fail-the-equality-test) is probably  duplicate. It confirms my suspicions above.

Comment: @squint Correct, was the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

According to [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/#objectid-valueof):

> Changed in version 2.2: In previous versions ObjectId.valueOf()
>   returns the ObjectId() object.

Since `user._id` and `message.authorId` are `ObjectId` objects the regular `==` compares their references thus you get `false`.

Try using either:

- `user._id.toString() == message.authorId.toString()`
- `user._id.equals(message.authorId)`
- upgrading to newer mongodb driver.